# Can I sync Ubuntu One contacts with my Android device?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

Am I able to sync contacts from my android device with Ubuntu One or is it only with Ubuntu desktop for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are only able to sync files, contacts for Android devices will be coming soon. Unfortunately its just syncing between Desktops (like you said) and via the website

Hope i helped, heres the website if you want to check: https://one.ubuntu.com/services/